# Stuck in git bash , I entered return key after writing the commit message ,, now i get the > symbol and cant exit back to normal $

Tags: git, git-bash

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have missed the last ' and now it shows me > and cant get out of it, see below * Thanks for your help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3t0D.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enter an additional `'` and then enter, or simply hit `CTRL`+`C` to cancel the command.

What is actually going on: quotes are actually interpreted by Bash, not git, and not finishing a quote is actually a valid case; the Bash interpreter will continue to take input, including returns, until it reaches a matching quote.